# Turn a variable into constant

Tags: c#, variables, constants

Does there exist any c# type/structure that enables a variable turning into a constant?
Maybe by setting a flag which fixes the value.

Example code:

```
foreach (Person p in group)
{
    if (p.Mood.Equals("bad"))
    {
        group.Mood = "bad";
        group.Mood.Fix(); // This should disable any further changing on group.Mood 
    }
    else
    {
        group.Mood = "good";
    }
}
```

The mood of the whole group should be "bad" if one persons mood is bad.
I know that I can implement something like this by myself but I use it that often that I can imaging that such a structure already exists.

I hope you're all in a good mood! ;)

Comment: Nothing built in for this. This pattern is sometimes called a "popsicle" or "popsicle immutability" (ie. you freeze it at some point). Also, I would advice against having a property which you can set but which ignores the new value, which is what you've shown would happen if a person has a bad mood, and the next one has a good mood. I would instead break out of the loop at that point and ignore the whole const/immutability problem.

Comment: Thank you, another question: Why is it called "popsicle"?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ice_pop

Comment: Okay, it's because it is first liquid and mostly frozen before "using"? ;)

Comment: That's correct, it has a liquid (mutable) state, and a frozen (immutable) state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would advice against doing this for the following reasons:

1. A property with a setter should be allowed to be set
2. A property with a setter should not simply ignore the value given to it

Secondly, why do you even look at more people in your collection if you've already established the final value?

I would instead change the code into one of the three following variants:

```
group.Mood = "good";
foreach (Person p in group)
{
    if (p.Mood.Equals("bad"))
    {
        group.Mood = "bad";
        break;
    }
}
```

or this:

```
string groupMood = "good";
foreach (Person p in group)
{
    if (p.Mood.Equals("bad"))
    {
        groupMood = "bad";
        break;
    }
}
group.Mood = groupMood;
```

or this:

```
if (group.Any(p => p.Mood == "bad"))
    group.Mood = "bad";
else
    group.Mood = "good";
```

If instead you want such a "Popsicle" type, here's one which you can try with [LINQPad](http://linqpad.net):

```
void Main()
{
    var i = new Popsicle<int>(10);
    i.Value = 25;
    i.Value = 33;
    i.Dump();

    i.Freeze(FrozenBehavior.IgnoreNewValues);
    i.Value = 17;
    i.Dump();

    i = new Popsicle<int>(10);
    i.Freeze(FrozenBehavior.ThrowException);
    i.Value = 17;
    i.Dump();
}

public class Popsicle<T>
{
    private T _Value;
    private FrozenBehavior? _FrozenBehavior;

    public Popsicle(T value = default(T))
    {
        _Value = value;
    }

    public T Value
    {
        get
        {
            return _Value;
        }

        set
        {
            if (_FrozenBehavior.HasValue)
            {
                switch (_FrozenBehavior.GetValueOrDefault())
                {
                    case FrozenBehavior.IgnoreNewValues:
                        break;

                    case FrozenBehavior.ThrowException:
                        throw new InvalidOperationException("This Popsicle<T> has been frozen and configured to throw exceptions if an attempt is made to change its value");

                    default:
                        throw new InvalidOperationException("This Popsicle<T> is in an invalid frozen state");
                }
            }
            else
                _Value = value;
        }
    }

    public void Freeze(FrozenBehavior behavior = FrozenBehavior.ThrowException)
    {
        if (!_FrozenBehavior.HasValue)
            _FrozenBehavior = behavior;
        else
            throw new InvalidOperationException("This Popsicle<T> has already been frozen, cannot re-freeze");
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        if (!_FrozenBehavior.HasValue)
            return _Value + " (unfrozen)";
        else switch (_FrozenBehavior)
        {
            case FrozenBehavior.IgnoreNewValues:
                return _Value + " (frozen: ignore)";

            case FrozenBehavior.ThrowException:
                return _Value + " (frozen: throw)";

            default:
                throw new InvalidOperationException("This Popsicle<T> is in an invalid frozen state");
        }
    }
}

public enum FrozenBehavior
{
    IgnoreNewValues,
    ThrowException
}
```

Comment: I solved it like you explained perceived like a thousand times. Therefore I asked if there is something like a special "type" for this case.

Thanks anyway! :)

Comment: Okay if there is no structure build in, I will implement the "Popsicle" type by myself. Thanks for your example!

Another question: Why is it called "popsicle"?

Answer (score 4):

No, the variable is made constant upon declaration. However, you could get something close with a property setter:

```
public string Mood
{
    set 
    {
       if(mood != "Bad")
            mood = value; 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With LinQ this can be done in a short way. Check if there is *any* person that has a bad mood, if so set the group-mood to `bad`, otherwise `good`.

```
group.Mood = group.Any(p => p.Mood == "bad") ? "bad" : "good";
```